# "Stable Release Publishing" part of developer.ubuntu.com?

Tags: stable-release-updates

Are non-commercial applications going to be published in the Software Center even if a new version of Ubuntu isn't out yet?

Answer (score 3):

As an answer, may I direct you to this link?

[Developer for Ubuntu information](http://developer.ubuntu.com/)

Note the number `3 - Publish link`.

I am not sure what you mean by

> even if a new version of Ubuntu isn't out yet?

It is my understanding that

a) Each version of Ubuntu has its own repositories of applications.

b) Canonical will not place software in the repositories (Ubuntu software Centre) if that application does not work well with the version of Ubuntu being serviced by a particular repository.

In other words, if a program/application does not work well with the latest version or it  does not meet the design standards that are set for Ubuntu applications, then the application will not be put in the Software Centre for the latest version.

Comment: I had this scenario in mind: Oneiric is already released, I develop an open-source app and submit it to the Review Board. It meets the design standards and works with Oneiric. Will it be published in Oneiric's repositories, just like a commercial app?